# What could be the reason for downvote on a question without any clarifications?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

[Two folders with weird names with huge size. What are those? What should I do with them?](https://superuser.com/questions/772803/two-folders-with-weird-names-with-huge-size-what-are-those-what-should-i-do-wi)

I just want to know the reason of downvote. I really do not feel that the question is technically wrong or posted without research.
What is the website for? I think, If there is a genuine problem and one is not able to find the answers, the user is supposed to post the question with all the information he have. What else can be done?

If a person is too much expert in a field, he should answer, otherwise if there is some lack of information, just post a comment and ask for it? Why downvoting and thus not letting the user do any further actions and making him helpless?

Please, I need a genuine answer so that I can gain knowledge and info on posting stuff at these websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the question is basically a duplicate of many other questions already asked on Superuser, e.g.:

[Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

[Random folder keeps appearing](https://superuser.com/questions/692683/random-folder-keeps-appearing)

[Strange folders are automaticaly created in my C:\ drive](https://superuser.com/questions/184597/strange-folders-are-automaticaly-created-in-my-c-drive?lq=1)

[Prevent "mysterious" folders in drive root from appearing without disabling Windows Update](https://superuser.com/questions/719467/prevent-mysterious-folders-in-drive-root-from-appearing-without-disabling-wind?lq=1)

Comment: Great answer, now if someone would put that back there in the question or the answers , we would be all set :-)

Answer (score 4):

It was probably downvoted just because you instantly assumed the names to be encrypted, which makes no sense at all.

We also have a very extensive help center, which, among other topics, covers [how to ask questions](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Here are a few more hints:

1. Don't prefix edits with "EDIT::".
2. Don't post information on how much RAM you have in a question that is about folders.
3. Properly format your post.

Comment: I never assumed the encryption part. And it makes sense actually, seeing the names in that format. Though thanks for suggestions, I have edited the question. I was under the impression that putting EDITs help those people who have answered it before. I will keep these in mind next time.

Comment: Also, making edits too many times affects anything?

Comment: Believe me, it does not make sense to encrypt the name of a folder when you can see the folder in the filesystem, open the folder and read all of its contents. What could possibly be gained from the name of the folder being encrypted? Who would decrypt the name? And what would the name be after it was decrypted that would necessitate the encryption?

Comment: That was what exactly I asked.

Comment: Making many edits isn't a problem in general. But it's an indication that you didn't put enough time/thought into writing the initial draft of your question. Take your time, gather all the information, write a post with proper formatting and you'll get good responses. The first draft is the most important one, because that's the one most people will see. Once your post is no longer on the front page, it is less likely that people will find it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but somebody just downvoted that again. Now? Or it is like, if you got one downvote you will keep getting?

Comment: @explorer there's no limit to up or downvotes that you can get. Don't get too hungup on downvotes

Comment: @explorer - You have not recieved any additional downvotes.  The most I ever saw on the question was 2 downvotes.  One was removed by the voter.

Comment: Ya, I guess so. Thank you all for help. It is really tough for a newbie to survive!